# Constructing a list of numbers in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I'm doing a programming assignment in Scheme where we have to develop a method of finding Happy Numbers. I've completed the meat (finding Happy numbers from a number n) but I'm having trouble constructing a list correctly.

Here is my code:

`(sosd num)` calculates `num`'s Happy Number and `(stop? num)` determines if `num` is a recursive number from a predetermined list.

```
(define (sspd_series num)
  (if (stop? num)
      (make-list num)
      (append (make-list(sosd num)) (make-list(sspd_series (sosd num))))
      )
  )

(define (make-list num)
  (cons num '())
  )
```

However while I want a list that looks like `(1 2 3 4 5)`, I get `(1 (2 (3 (4 (5)))))`. I've tried `cons` instead of `append` and I get something different, but not what I'm looking for.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `stop?` and `sosd` are correctly implemented, you just have to build a proper list as output, use `cons` for that. This is how:

```
(define (sspd_series num)
  (if (stop? num)
      (list (sosd num))
      (cons (sosd num)
            (sspd_series (sosd num)))))
```

You can optimize the implementation by calculating `sosd` only once at the start of the procedure, and storing it in a variable. Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks very much for your quick reply :D

Answer (score 1):

The smart thing is to find a way to create your list in reverse order.  Imagine you start with `'()` you make `'(3)` with `(cons 3 '())` and you make `'(2 3)` with `(cons 2 '(3))`. As inspiration here is how to reverse a list:

```
(define (my-reverse lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (cdr lst) (cons (car lst) acc)))))
```